# Can Azure SQL use signed stored procedures

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to find out of Azure SQL can sign and run a signed stored procedure.  Seems the documentation says "SQL Server" but not "Azure SQL" under the learn.microsoft.com pages.  Anyone know? I'm getting permissions errors when I try to run the commands necessary and wonder if that's why, or its some permissions issues.

Comment: If you mean can they be used in Azure SQL Database, and not a SQL Server in Azure, then I don't believe so, no. Azure SQL Databases are contained databases though, so you  could easily just ensure the objects have the same owner and ownership chaining would kick in. You don't really need signed stored procedures in Azure SQL Databases.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can, per a support contact and a demo.  The difference is that you need to make the login in the master and the account in the DB you want to have the procedure in.  Otherwise it works fine.